# Applying LINQ to Objects Group By and Sort By to generic List<T> (C#)

Tags: linq, group-by, ienumerable

I am having a hard time creating working Group By and Sort By clauses against a generic List myList.
 myList has a list of property 'Settings' which itself contains a list of 'child' properties for each business.

I want to group by a Industry and within each Industry, sort by business name.  My intent would be this:

```
string groupSetting = "Industry";
sortSetting = "BusinessName";
myList.GroupBy(p => p.Settings.Find(s => s.Name == groupSetting)).OrderBy(p => p.Settings.Find(t => t.Name == sortSetting));
```

However I am getting the error : 
'*System.Linq.IGrouping does not contain a definition for Settings and no extension method Settings accepting a first argument of type System.Linq.Igrouping could be found....*' indicating I cannot invoke the order by clause without some transformation or additional treatment.

I have tried all sorts of things to split this out and get it working, but I am missing something.   Any help appreciated

Comment: What do you mean "List myList. myList has a list of property 'Settings'"  Can you post sample code for setting this up (i.e. how do myList and its elements get populated?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem is that `GroupBy` doesn't return a single list of settings, it returns a "list-of-lists". This is the `IGrouping` which you are seeing.

You need to iterate over each group in the `IGrouping`, sort that group, and then iterate over each item within the group. Observe:

```
public static void Main( string[] args )
{
    var groupSetting = "Industry";

    // step 1: group the data. Note this doesn't actually create copies of the data as
    // it's all lazy loaded
    // BEWARE. If a company doesn't have the "Industry" setting, this will throw an exception
    var grouped = companies.GroupBy(c => c.Settings.First(s => s.Name == groupSetting).Value);
    foreach( var group in grouped )
    {
        Console.WriteLine(group.Key);// this is the Value that came out of the GroupBy

        // Note how we have to do the ordering within each individual group. 
        // It doesn't make sense to try group them in one hit like in your question
        foreach( var item in group.OrderBy(bus => bus.Name) )
            Console.WriteLine(" - " + item.Name);
    }
}
```

Data structures provided for clarity:

```
struct Setting { public string Name; public string Value; }
struct Business { public string Name; public IEnumerable<Setting> Settings; }

static IEnumerable<Business> companies = new[]{
    new Business{ Name = "XYZ Inc.", Settings = new[]{ 
        new Setting{ Name="Age", Value="27"},
        new Setting{ Name="Industry", Value="IT"}
    }},
    new Business{ Name = "Programmers++", Settings = new[]{ 
        new Setting{ Name="Age", Value="27"},
        new Setting{ Name="Industry", Value="IT"}
    }},
    new Business{ Name = "Jeff's Luxury Salmon", Settings = new[]{ 
        new Setting{ Name="Age", Value="63"},
        new Setting{ Name="Industry", Value="Sports"}
    }},
    new Business{ Name = "Bank of Khazakstan", Settings = new[]{ 
        new Setting{ Name="Age", Value="30"},
        new Setting{ Name="Industry", Value="Finance"}
    }},
};
```

This produces the following output: Copy/paste the code and run it and play with it

```
IT
 - Programmers++
 - XYZ Inc.
Sports
 - Jeff's Luxury Salmon
Finance
 - Bank of Khazakstan
```